How to change orientation of normals in open3d
I'm trying to change the orientetion of normals with open3d, this is the current situation of the normals:

I need to do this change of orientation for the surface recostruction of the face.
How can I change the normal orienterion?

Oh, wow, looks very cool. Dnk if this helps, but normals usually get's wrong sign if your mesh wasn't aligned to vertexes using clockwise rules. Basically order of the vertexes in each polygon should be clockwise. However maybe if you'll add a bit more details on how you ended up in this situation it will give a bit more ideas on what might be useful for you.

Thank you for responding, i already find out how to change the orientetion with this function, link

You just need to pass the point cloud to the function orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane()
The function works with point clouds in tensor form, so import your cloud like this:
# Import point cloud
    pc_tensor = o3d.t.io.read_point_cloud("path/to/your/point/cloud.pcd")
# Estimate normals (we use 12 knn)
    pc_tensor.estimate_normals(12, None)
# Orient normals (it can take some time for 1 Milion points)
    pc_tensor.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane(k=12, lambda=10.0, cos = 0.5)

when passing the arguments to the function, don't put the names, just the values: pc_tensor.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane(12, 10.0, 0.5)
The parameters passed to this function make the estimation of the normals more robust.
k (int) – k nearest neighbour for graph reconstruction for normal propagation. It must be equal to the number of knn used to estimate the normals, otherwise the process will take even longer.
lambda (float) – A non-negative real parameter that influences the distance metric used to identify the true neighbors of a point in complex geometries. It penalizes the distance between a point and the tangent plane defined by the reference point and its normal vector, helping to mitigate misclassification issues encountered with traditional Euclidean distance metrics (sugested value, lambda=10).

cos_alpha_tol (float) – Cosine threshold angle used to determine the inclusion boundary of neighbors based on the direction of the normal vector (sugested value = 0.5).

For more information:
https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.html#open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.orient_normals_consistent_tangent_plane
Papper:
https://eugeniovaretti.github.io/meshreco/Piazza_Valentini_Varetti_MeshReconstructionFromPointCloud_2023.pdf
